# OpenLayers2 search on feature

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, search

My code works normally but I want to add a search box and with coming value (like addresses) which I search on WMS and focus on those for which value exists. I mean like that I have search box and I give the parameters for example `New York Washington Apartment` and in the background search on WMS and zoom to New York Washington and select. I searched samples but I didn't find how I can do that.

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);               
                var tiled = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                    "bla",
                    "http://bla.com:8080/geoserver/Kaski/wms",
                    {
                        LAYERS: 'bla',
                        STYLES: '',
                        format: "image/png",
                        tiled: true,
                        tilesOrigin : map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom
                    },
                    {
                        buffer: 0,
                        displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                        isBaseLayer: true,
                        yx : {'EPSG:2322' : true}
                    } 
                );
                 layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                    "Bina",
                    "http://bla.com:8080/geoserver/bla/wms",
                    {
                        LAYERS: 'bla:bla',
                        format: "image/png",
                    },
                    {
                        opacity: 0.2,
                        isBaseLayer: false
                    });
                    var select = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Selection", { styleMap: new OpenLayers.Style(OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["select"]) });

                map.addLayers([layer, tiled, select]);

                control = new OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature({ protocol: OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS.fromWMSLayer(layer) });
                control.events.register("featureselected", this, function (e) {
                    alert(e.feature.fid);
                    select.addFeatures([e.feature]);
                });
                control.events.register("featureunselected", this, function(e) { select.removeFeatures([e.feature]); });

                map.addControl(control);
                control.activate();
                layer.mergeNewParams({'CQL_FILTER': "fid = ADRES_BINA.125063"});

                for (var j = 0; j < control.features.length; j++) {
                    var geom = control.features[j].geometry;
                }

                map.zoomToExtent(bounds);
            }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Do you have the address in your data? or do you wish to geocode and zoom to any arbitrary address?

Comment: on geoserver i have all table for example country, town, street

i search with feature name and and find feature ,select it and focus. That's all heron has query filter like that

Answer (score 2):

Try setting up your vector layer with a filter, strategy, and protocol. and event handler.
I have not included any protocol code. The protocol will bind you wms layer to the vector layer, so to speak.

Possibly;

```
  strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],

  filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
    property: "fid",
    value: some value
  });

  vector.events.on({
    featureadded: function() {
    map.zoomToExtent(vector.getDataExtent());
  });
```

then as the attribute changes in your code, set the filter and refresh the layer

```
  filter.value = some value;

  vector.refresh();
```

Comment: i couldn't do that :/ how will i add these code. ?

Comment: I am not sure what you could not do. Is you issue with setting up the vector layer with a filter, protocol, strategy etc, or are you unable to set the filter value?

Answer (score 2):

You can't search a WMS for a textual string, it's not part of the WMS standard.  You will need to search some other service, perhaps a gazetteer, perhaps a WFS, and use the results of that service to give you a bounding box which you can use to define your WMS request.